# How can I get data from array data field from Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore and there is a array data in field. So how can I get data from array individually?

[image]

Comment: Do you want entire Array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the values within `ip_range` array, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
rootRef.collection("aic").document("ceo").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getKey().equals("ip_range")) {
                        Log.d("TAG", entry.getValue().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Another approach would be:

```
rootRef.collection("products").document("06cRbnkO1yqyzOyKP570").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) document.get("ip_range");
                Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In both cases, the output in your logcat will be:

```
[172.16.11.1, 172.16.11.2]
```

Comment: Thanx @Alex Mamo. It is working. But how did you know the collection & document name, however I have wrapped it in the image.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked! I knew the collection and document name because of [this](https://ibb.co/k058wz) :)

Comment: second solution above, i got warning "Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>'"

Comment: @LatiefAnwar You can use an annotation to suppress it.