# How to retrieve data from Firestore that stored as an Array and set them as EditText values in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have stored some data as an array in `Firestore` using the following code. Now, I want to get those values and put them one by one into the `EditText`s. How can I do that?

```
    private fun addZipToFirebase() {

    val zipList = createListOfZipCodes()

    mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
        .document(FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserID())
        .update("zip_codes", zipList)

        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@AssignZIPCodeActivity,
                "Zip Codes updates successfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.e(
                javaClass.simpleName,
                exception.message,
                exception
            )
        }
}
```

Edit:

I am trying with the following code to get the data. I want each Zip Code under the field name zip_codes (in the screenshot), in each `EditText` (etPinCodeOne, etPinCodeTwo, etPinCodeThree and so on). But with following code what I am getting is all the zip codes together in the `EditText`. Exctely like, [123456, 789456, 132645,798654, 798654, 799865, 764997, 497646, 946529, 946585]. I want each codes in each `EditText`.

```
   private fun getZipCodesFromFirebase() {

        mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
            .document(FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserID())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                val list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
                list.add(document["zip_codes"].toString())
Toast.makeText(this@AssignZIPCodeActivity,list.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            binding.etZipCodeOne.setText(list[0])

                }

            }
```

Can someone help me with this please?

[image]

Comment: You can find the documentation to get a document [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document). Could you please share any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Since the value I want to get is stored as an `ArrayList` and I want to get them as an ArrayList` I have no idea how to write. I have already gone through the link that you have given but the problem again is the Array.

Comment: Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52538893/13130697) that might help you. You just need to defined an array in your code: `ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) document.get("ip_range");`

Comment: Can you take a look at my question now, I have updated some code and my firebase database structure.

Comment: I tried `.document(FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserID()).get("zip_codes")` , as in your last comment. I am getting error `Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Source was expected` . Please note that I want code for `Kotlin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to get the `zip_codes` array, you need to have inside your User class, a property called zip_codes that needs to be declared of type List:

```
val zip_codes: List<String>
```

Now, to get it accordingly, please use the following lines of code:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val usersRef = rootRef.collection("users")
val uidRef = usersRef.document(uid)
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val document = task.result
        if (document.exists()) {
            val zip_codes = document.toObject(User::class.java).zip_codes
            //Do what you need to do with your list
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.exception)
    }
}
```

Since you are getting multiple zip codes, you should consider using a ListView, or even better a RecyclerView, rather than EditTexts.

Comment: It works like a charm. I just replaced `usersRef` with `followingRef`. Also, `task.getResult()` with `result` as suggested by Android Studio. All developers are lucky to have a mentor like you. Thank you so much. I will use a `RecyclerView` as you said. If the changes I made are correct, then please update your answer too.

Comment: Yes, I just updated the answer with the correct data. And yes, `result` is a property within the class, so it makes sense to use it instead of a method call. You're very welcome!