# How to get array data from Firestore? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array in Firestore. How can I get array items? I need `streamers` array type of string.

What I try is:

```
firebaseFireStore.collection("Agencies")
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            if (e == null) {
                val documents = snapshot?.documents
                if(documents != null) {
                    val list = mutableListOf<Ajanslar>()
                    for (document in documents) {

                        val agencyName = document.get("agencyName").toString()
                        val coverImage = document.get("coverImage").toString()
                        val owner = document.get("owner").toString()
                        val platform = document.get("platform").toString()
                        val streamers = document.get("streamers")
                        val newAjans = Ajanslar(agencyName,coverImage,owner,platform,streamers)
                        list.add(newAjans)
                    }
                    ajansListRepo.value = list
                }
            }
        }
```

Streamers give error and says `Type mismatch. Required: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<String> /* = java.util.ArrayList<String> */ Found: Any?`

My firestore is like that:
[image]

I found an answer like that in Java but I couldn't do it.

```
rootRef.collection("products").document("06cRbnkO1yqyzOyKP570").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document.exists()) {
            ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) document.get("ip_range");
            Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537965/how-can-i-get-data-from-array-data-field-from-cloud-firestore) and the solution is quite simple in Kotlin. As I see in your screenshot, the `streamers` field is an array of strings. When you call [DocumentSnapshot#get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#get(java.lang.String)), the type of object that is returned is [Any](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/index.html)  and not a `List<String>`. If you need that, you have to explicitly perform a cast to such an object. So please change the following line of code:

```
val streamers = document.get("streamers")
```

Into:

```
val streamers = document.get("streamers") as List<String>
```